# why the address of dynamic array is different from the first element address?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int* q = new int[3];
    cout << &q[0] << endl;
    cout << q << endl;  
    cout << &q << endl; // why here is different?

    int p[3];
    cout << &p[0] << endl;
    cout << p << endl;
    cout << &p << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

here is my code, I use new to create dynamic arrays, but the array address really confused me, why &q is different?

Comment: `p` is an array. `q` is a pointer. Why do you expect the same behavior for different types?

Comment: `&q` is a pointer-to-pointer. `q` and `&q[0]` are just pointers. No reason they should be the same, and any good book would explain.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but this code doesn't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 5):

The expression `&q` is a pointer to the variable `q`, which is indeed different from where `q` is pointing.

You could look at it like this:

```
+----+     +---+     +------+------+------+
| &q | --> | q | --> | q[0] | q[1] | q[2] |
+----+     +---+     +------+------+------+
```

---

On the other hand `p` is an array, where `&p` is a pointer to the array itself:

```
+----+     +------+------+------+
| &p | --> | p[0] | p[1] | p[2] |
+----+     +------+------+------+
```

---

There's also a very large semantic difference between `&q` and `&p`: Their types.

The type of `&q` is `int**`, while `&p` is of the type `int (*)[3]`.

This also explains why `&p` and `&p[0]` seems to be the same, they both point to the same location. But here too there's a semantic difference, the type of `&p[0]` is `int*`.

Lastly, arrays can *decay* to a pointer to its first element, which means that `p` is the same as `&p[0]`, and even have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Because q is a pointer, it doesn't decay to a pointer like an array would. In this case &q means the pointer to the pointer q, whereas &q[0] means the pointer to q dereferenced, in other words q itself.

Answer (score 0):

`p` is an array. `q` is a pointer. An array contains the actual data. Therefore a pointer `&p` to the array `p` points directly to the data.

The pointer `q` is a variable that contains the address of the dynamic array. The address of the pointer is different to the address of the data.

This code snippet describes what happens:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // new int[3] creates an array
    // int *q creates a pointer pointing to the array
    int* q = new int[3];
    cout << &q[0] << endl;
    cout << q << endl;  
    cout << &q << endl; // why here is different?

    // int p[3] creates an array
    int p[3];
    // int *pp creates a pointer pointing to the array
    int *pp = p;
    cout << &pp[0] << endl;
    cout << pp << endl;
    cout << &pp << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

The difference is that you can't access the dynamic array in the first case. It doesn't have a name. It can only be accessed through the pointer `p`.

In the second case the array has a name `p` and you can access it directly or through the pointer `pp`.

Answer (score 0):

The address of dynamic array is the `q`. `&q` is the address of address of dynamic array.