# How is the value (pointer) of an array declared on the stack stored in memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, stack

Recently, I realized that if I create an array on the stack, then the following values ​​will be equal to it:

- the address of the variable itself on the stack
- the value of this variable (i.e. the same pointer)
- the address of the first element of this array

It turns out that when I create an array of type `T` and size `N`, an area of ​​`sizeof(T)*N` bytes appears on the stack. For the code below, all three addresses will be the same:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int automaticArray[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    cout << "Variable value = " << automaticArray << ", variable adress = " << &automaticArray << ", first element addres = " << &automaticArray[0] << endl;
}
```

If I do the same with an array in a dynamic memory area, it will not be correct. The address of the variable itself (the one that will be on the stack) will differ from the two remaining values.

This is logical, because I store only the pointer on the stack, and 8 bytes are allocated for it. The array itself is located somewhere on the heap. For the example below, the addresses will not be the same:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int* dynamicArray = new int[5] {0};

    cout << "Variable value = " << dynamicArray << ", variable adress = " << &dynamicArray << ", first element addres = " << &dynamicArray[0] << endl;
}
```

How is it possible that when creating an array on the stack (consider an example for ints), the first eight bytes will simultaneously contain a pointer to the array (i.e. a pointer to this variable itself), and the first 2 elements from array?

My guess is that the value of the variable (the address of the first element of the array) is not stored anywhere.

I checked this through GodBolt, but I'm not good at assembly, and I'm not 100% sure that my guess is correct.

[image]

Comment: You've just discovered one of C++ deeply held secrets: there is no such thing as an "array" in C++. It's a myth. A legend. An array is an artificial entity. A pointer, such as a `dynamicArray` is a real, breathing, living thing. What you're seeing is the difference between the two. In the case of a "real" (double air-quotes) array, there is no other option except to get the same memory address for a "real" (double air-quotes) array, since there's nothing else out there. But in case of a pointer you have different things: the pointer, and what it points to.

Comment: Side notes, it looks like you're learning C++ from a source that needs some updating. `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not standard C++ and should not be used., `using namespace std;` is not recommended. And new/delete should hardly every be used in modern C++. Use `std::array` for fixed size arrays (that at least behaves like an object), `std::vector<int>` for dynamically allocated (and resizable) arrays. And if you ever need to allocate memory yourself use `std::make_unique` (not new).

Comment: `automaticArray` is an array while `dynamicArray` is a pointer, a pointer to first element of an array, not an array. Arrays can decay to pointers to first element but that doesnt mean that arrays are pointers or vice versa

Comment: "...the first eight bytes will simultaneously contain a pointer to the array (i.e. a pointer to this variable itself) and the first 2 elements from array?" they do not. You need to read about array to pointer decay: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-conversion-aka-decay

Comment: generally its a good idea to experiment, but unfortunately generally there is a limit to what you can learn about c++ by experimenting. Mainly due to undefined/unspecified/etc behavior the output of some code example can be very misleading.

Comment: Similar concept: Where do you find the address of a reference? Answer is you don't. References have no address. They are just another name for an existing variable.

Comment: The *truth* is in the assembly language listing.  Usually, the compiler knows the start of all elements in the *stack*.  Most programs maintain a *stack pointer* which points to the stack.  Locations (addresses) of items on the stack are referred to based on an offset from the *stack pointer*.  This includes parameters, and return addresses.  (Note some parameters may be passed by register and not on the stack).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are \`&array\` and \`array\` pointing to the same address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807208) and [why the address of dynamic array is different from the first element address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63114268)

Comment: For more fun / possible explanation: [What is the relationship between an array and its address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54833763)

Answer (score 1):

> how is it possible that when creating an array on the stack we (consider an example for ints) in the first eight bytes will simultaneously contain a pointer to the array (i.e. a pointer to this variable itself) and the first 2 elements from array?

It is not possible.  You are misinterpreting your output.  In most cases where a subexpression of array type appears in an expression, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the first array element.  This is a special exception to the usual rule for lvalue conversion, with the result that

> ```
> cout << "Variable value = " << automaticArray
> ```

does not, in fact, print the contents of the array.  It is 100% equivalent to

```
cout << "Variable value = " << &automaticArray[0]
```

.  This behavior was inherited from C at the birth of C++, and has remained unchanged since then.

> My guess is that the value of the variable (the address of the first element of the array) is not stored anywhere.

Be careful.  Arrays and pointers are not at all the same thing.  The *address* of the array indeed is not stored in memory in any accessible form.  But the *value* of the array is an aggregate composed of the values of its elements, and that certainly is stored in memory.

Comment: By “array value” I meant what will happen when casting it to a pointer. Those. not the array elements themselves, but a pointer to the first of them.

Comment: But how can this be, because in order to get &automaticArray[0] we must do &*(automaticArray +0). Those. again you need to know exactly the value of automaticArray

Comment: @BychkovArthur, the value of an array is the contents of the memory it occupies, interpreted according to the array type.  That's what "value" *means* in this context.  And for an array, that is a composite of the values of the array elements.  I'm uncertain what you mean by casting to a pointer, you not having presented an example, but note well that expressions such as `static_cast<int *>(automaticArray)` and `(int *) automaticArray` are among those where array-to-pointer conversion is automatically performed, so the casts are pointer-to-pointer conversions, not array-to-pointer conversions.

Comment: @BychkovArthur, how can that *not* be?  Again, the lvalue `automaticArray` is automatically converted to a pointer when evaluated (with a very few exceptions).  The indexing operator is an operator *on pointers*, not on arrays, and you correctly observe that `automaticArray[0]` is equivalent to `*(automaticArray + 0)`, and therefore that the address-of operator has the same effect on each.  But `&*` composes to the identity operation, as does `+ 0`, so that boils down exactly to `&automaticArray[0] == automaticArray`.  But *only* because of the automatic conversions involved.

Comment: @BychkovArthur, yes, the compiler does need to know the address of the array.  But it does not need to *store* that address in memory in order to know it.  Not any more than it needs to store the address of an `int`, though it needs to know that, too, to be able to read and write it.

Comment: can you tell me if I understood everything correctly in the end?
1) Stupid question, but: is the term array value exactly a collection of array elements interpreted in accordance with the type of the array? Is the array value not a pointer that is obtained by decaying to a pointer?

Comment: 2) When creating an array, the compiler simply knows the shift along which this array lies. When we subsequently access `automaticArray` (and no decay occurs), it simply calculates the address by shift (the pointer to the first element itself is not stored anywhere). When we access by index, use `[i]`, then we simply have pointer arithmetic and an expression like `automaticArray[i]` is interpreted by the compiler as `*(automaticArray + i)`, but it can calculate the address `automaticArray` by shift, as I described in the sentence above.

Comment: (continuation of the second point) As a result, the array elements themselves are stored in `sizeof(T) * N` cells, and the value of what comes out after the `automaticArray` decays to the pointer is known to the compiler as a simple shift; this value is not stored anywhere.

Comment: 3) When we do `&automaticArray` with us, firstly, no decay occurs, and secondly, the address of this variable is calculated by the compiler in exactly the same way as for any variable, for example: `int a = 5; &a`.

Comment: @BychkovArthur, (1) yes, that sounds right.  An array is an object -- a region of storage -- composed of one or more other objects arranged contiguously in memory.  An array value is the value of the memory occupied by an array, interpreted according to the array's type, or an analogous value not necessarily associated with actual storage.  An array value is *not*, itself, a pointer value.

Comment: @BychkovArthur, (2) there is nothing to distinguish arrays from any other declared object with respect to how the compiler knows their addresses.  It knows them because it *chooses* them, either in absolute terms or as an offset from some base address, such as the stack pointer.  The latter is enough to determine an absolute address when that is needed.  The details of how and when it performs such computations are not specified by the C language.  Each implementation chooses how to do it.  [...]

Comment: [...] The indexing operator is *strictly* an operator on pointers.  Often, indexing operators are applied to the pointers resulting from array decay, but that does not make that operand any less a pointer.  The compiler knows the pointer value to which an array expression decays because that's its job, which it can and typically does perform at compile time.  The details are, again, implementation specific.  It does not need to store object addresses in memory as such in order to know them.

Comment: @BychkovArthur (3) yes, exactly.  In particular, situations where an array is the operand of a unary `&` operator are one of the very few exceptions in which arrays do not decay to pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ use std::array and std::vector. Do not get hung up on pointers to arrays if you don't have to. If you ever need a pointer you can use  `.data()` method on both std::array, and std::vector

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

// you cannot return "C" style (stack) arrays
// but you can return std::array
std::array<int,4> make_array()
{
    std::array<int,4> values{1,2,3,4};
    return values;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int,4> array1 = make_array(); // Allocated on the stack

    std::array<int,4> array2{2,3,4,5}; // Also allocated on the stack    

    std::vector<int> vector{1,2,3,4}; // Allocatd (for you) on the heap;

    // when vector goes out of scope memory is deallocated for you
}
```

Comment: I do this for educational purposes. It is clear that there is a vector and an array. But my question was, where is the value of this pointer stored?

Comment: @BychkovArthur • `automaticArray` is not a pointer, it's an array.  There is no "pointer" to be stored.  An array will *decay* into a pointer to the first element, as a C-style affordance (which C++ does as well, to be backwards compatible with C).

Comment: And the "bad" thing about pointer decay is that you will loose all size information of the array and it is the main reason I avoid "C" style arrays altogether (leads to all kinds of unsafe code and out of bound bugs).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `dynamicArray` is a pointer, while `automaticArray` is an array.

The easier case is `dynamicArray`. `new int[5] {0};` allocates an array and returns a pointer to its first element. In memory you have

```
 ----------------             
 | dynamicArray |   ------
 ----------------        |
                         |
                         v
                        -------------
                        | 0 1 2 3 4 |
                        -------------
```

That is, you have a pointer to `int`. Its value is the address of the first element of the newly allocated array. Hence `&dynamicArray[0] == dynamicArray`. The address of that pointer however, is some other remote address, because the pointer is stored separate from the actual array.

Whith `automaticArray` things are different. In memory you only have

```
                        -------------
                        | 0 1 2 3 4 |
                        -------------
```

And thats it. What you are missing is array to pointer decay. In this line

```
cout << automaticArray << &automaticArray << &automaticArray[0] << endl;
```

All three addresses are the same, because `automaticArray` does decay to a pointer when passed to `std::ostream::operator<<`. That is because there is no overload that would take a reference to an array of 5 integers. You could write one yourself. For illustration, consider this:

```
#include <iostream>


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, int (&arr)[5]) {
    for (int i=0;i<5;++i) out << arr[i] << " ";
    return out;
}


int main() {

    int automaticArray[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::cout << automaticArray;
}
```

[Which outputs:](https://godbolt.org/z/j85jrbjeo)

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

You wouldn't actually write code like this, but its only to demonstrate that `automaticArray` is not a pointer. Its an array. It potentially does decay to a pointer to the first element of the array. And thats what happens in your code, because there is no `<<` overload that takes a reference to array. But if you pass the array via reference then no to-pointer decay  happens. In the above example `automaticArray` is an array and `arr` is a reference to that array. No pointers are involved.